# Explain the use of Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning

In the proposition below from [Measure Theory and Probability by Athreya and Lahiri](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387329031), DCT was used to justify the existence of $t$ in the first line of the proof.

[image]

But I can't think how this was applied from the DCT as provided in page 7:

[image]

Can somebody explain how this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}|f(x)|\chi_{\{|f|>t\}}=0 ~~~~\text{a.e.}$$

(Because $f\in L^1$ if we had a set of positive measure that was infinite, the integral would be infinite as well)

And $|f(x)|\chi_{\{|f|>t\}}$ is dominated by an integrable function, namely $|f|$ (as $f\in L^1$), so we have:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \int_{|f|>t}|f|~d\mu=\lim_{t\to\infty} \int_{\Omega} |f(x)|\chi_{\{|f|>t\}} ~d\mu=\int_{\Omega}0~d\mu=0$$

Then just apply definition of convergence of numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the speedy reply, +ZacharySelk.